# how to loop string or button in python?

Tags: python

i'm new with python.
I have a problem:
I would like you to click a button to infinity. how to do?

```
random_int = randint(15, 30)
print('Sleeping for {} seconds'.format(random_int))
time.sleep(random_int)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='control-button']").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a forever running `while` loop.

```
import time
from numpy.random import randint

while True:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='control-button']").click()
    time.sleep(randint(15, 30))
```

Comment: thx for reply,
I tried but it gives me this error:
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: all I need is a button to be clicked x times every 15-30 seconds